# Can a UAG Reverse Proxy work on external ports other than 443

Tags: reverse-proxy, vmware-uag

I have a VMWare Unified Access Gateway Appliance v3.10 which I'm using as a Reverse Proxy server.

The reverse proxy is working great, but it only listens to port 443 on the external-interface side.

I would like to reverse-proxy port 3000.  That is, I would like **both**
`https://uag.mydomain.com/`  to reverse-proxy to `https://internal.mydomain.com/`
**AND**
`https://uag.mydomain.com:3000/`  to reverse-proxy to `https://internal.mydomain.com:3000/`

The internal part works fine.  The question is, how can I (or can I at all?) get the UAG to listen to port 3000?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Here is my config (at least, the parts that aren't completely empty).  Not that much to it.

```
Proxy Destination URL   https://internal.mydomain.com:3000
External URL            https://uag.mydomain.com:3000
Proxy Pattern           /.*
```

Note that there is no `/` at the end of either URL.  I left out "Proxy Host Pattern" because both proxies are using the same hostname, and I was afraid that one would overtake the other.

When the UAG tries to connect to its own port 3000, I get

```
root@uag-7a17d053-0619-41f3-ae74-5d75879b8ea6 [ ~ ]# curl -kI https://localhost:3000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

even though port 443 works fine

```
root@uag-7a17d053-0619-41f3-ae74-5d75879b8ea6 [ ~ ]# curl -kI https://localhost:443/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Horizon-Desktops-and-Apps/changing-default-ports-on-UAG/td-p/2909147

tells me that it is not possible to use a port other than 443.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/Unified-Access-Gateway/3.10/com.vmware.uag-310-deploy-config.doc/GUID-5AF13543-0547-40E6-BCF6-716AB2DD7694.html) you can configure multiple reverse proxies and you can configure the external URL in the format `https://<host:port>`.

Comment: I configured the "External URL" to be `https://uag.mydomain.com:3000` , but the machine is still not listening to port 3000.  I still get "Connection Refused"  I will update my question with my entire config